# Add to Calendar link from website to mobile app

Tags: android, ios, iphone, responsive-design, calendar

Is there a way to create a link from a responsive website that would open and add an event to the app installed on a mobile phone or tablet?

For example, this event on a responsive website. Whenever the "Add to Calendar" button is clicked on a mobile device, the event needs to be added to an installed app, be it in iOS or Android. Also if there are numerous apps installed like Google Calendar, Outlook, and/or iCal, the device should show a prompt to the user asking what app should be used if there are no default app selected.

[image]

I could do this by generating an .ics file on click but that would mean more taps and navigation for a user. Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Thank you.